# is it possible in JavaScript to assigne multiline string to variable like in C# by using @"text"?

Tags: javascript, text, multiline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings)

In c# I can do this:

```
string str = @"asd 
dsa 
blah blah blah";
```

How can i do the same in JavaScript? + every string is bad idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `\` backslash to the end of every line:

```
var string = "Hello\
              world\
              this\
              is\
              a string!";
```

Comment: Hrm, I could have sworn that this is not standardized or supported by all common browsers.